# Solr not indexing files?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I indexed these many files from the command line by using the 
`bin/post -c NewProject path/to/data` command and it gave the following message but ...

```
105381 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/NewProject/update...
Time spent: 0:03:58.747
```

...in the admin page, it still shows no files indexed. What am I doing wrong? Or am I missing any steps?
[Admin Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K38o8.png)

Comment: it might not have committed the file..? and are you checking in the same core..?

Comment: Not committed the file? Yes, I started solr. Ran the indexing command. Checked the same core.

Comment: I mean indexes might not yet committed ...could be one of the case where you are not able to get the data...Is your indexing completed...?

Comment: Yes, those were the last lines in the indexing process.

Comment: Is the procedure right? 
I created a core. My data was outside the solr directory. I just linked to it. Is that fine?

Comment: yes...thats should be fine...I am wondering whats could be the issue then...?...how are you indexing it...Dataimport handler...?

Comment: No. I have created a new core. Then I just run the command as shown in the question. I am not using a DIH, I think.

Comment: Should I be doing something else to index files?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right core in the Admin UI? OR perhaps you need to reload the UI page itself.

Can you also include at least one of the actual 'sending files' lines showing what file extension and to what handler it went.